# How to setup azure application gateway with App services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-appservice

I am trying to setup azure application gateway with self signed cert. for the first step without https, I am trying to establish the http with port 80. when I try to browse the application with the appgateway public IP it is redirecting it to https://myappname.azurewebsites.net:80, I am not sure whats going wrong here. I specifically write a rewrite rule to override to the the site but in that case the site loads without redirection(as expected) and working fine. I want to understand why its navigating to myappname.azurewebsites.net:80 instead of just myappname.azurewebsites.net. I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=defaultdomain%2Cazure-powershell)

Here is the simplified version of the PowerShell script for the same with no existing port 80 rule

```
$webAppFQDN = "myapp.azurewebsites.net"
$rgName = "acsrg001"
$appGwName = "acsag002"
$appGwBackendPoolNameForAppSvc = "acspebpool001"
$httpSettingsName = "acspehttpsettings001"
$httpListenerName = "acspelistener001"
$reqRoutingRuleName = "acspelatestrule001"

$gw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
Add-AzApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -Name $appGwBackendPoolNameForAppSvc -ApplicationGateway $gw -BackendFqdns $webAppFQDN
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw

$gw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
Add-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name $httpSettingsName -ApplicationGateway $gw -Protocol Https -Port 443 -PickHostNameFromBackendAddress -CookieBasedAffinity Disabled -RequestTimeout 30
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw

$gw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$port = $gw.FrontendPorts | Where-Object {$_.Port -eq 80}
$listener = $gw.HttpListeners | Where-Object {$_.Protocol.ToString().ToLower() -eq "http" -and $_.FrontendPort.Id -eq $port.Id}
if ($listener -eq $null){
    $frontendIpConfig = $gw.FrontendIpConfigurations | Where-Object {$_.PublicIpAddress -ne $null}
    Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name $httpListenerName -ApplicationGateway $gw -Protocol Http -FrontendIPConfiguration $frontendIpConfig -FrontendPort $port
    Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw
}

$gw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$httpListener = Get-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener -Name $httpListenerName -ApplicationGateway $gw
$httpSettings = Get-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -Name $httpSettingsName -ApplicationGateway $gw
$backendPool = Get-AzApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -Name $appGwBackendPoolNameForAppSvc -ApplicationGateway $gw
Add-AzApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -Name $reqRoutingRuleName -ApplicationGateway $gw -RuleType Basic -BackendHttpSettings $httpSettings -HttpListener $httpListener -BackendAddressPool $backendPool -Priority 1
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $gw

$gw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $appGwName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
Get-AzApplicationGatewayBackendHealth -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $appGwName
```

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same script in my environment I got the same result like below:***

[image]

```
Sku                                 : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSApplicationGatewaySku
SslPolicy                           : 
GatewayIPConfigurations             : {appGatewayIpConfig}
AuthenticationCertificates          : {}
SslCertificates                     : {}
TrustedRootCertificates             : {}
TrustedClientCertificates           : {}
FrontendIPConfigurations            : {appGwPublicFrontendIp}
FrontendPorts                       : {port_80}
Probes                              : {}
BackendAddressPools                 : {back, pool1, backendpool007}
BackendHttpSettingsCollection       : {http}
SslProfiles                         : {}
HttpListeners                       : {listhttp}
UrlPathMaps                         : {}
RequestRoutingRules                 : {rule1}
RewriteRuleSets                     : {}
RedirectConfigurations              : {rule1}
WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration : 
FirewallPolicy                      : 
AutoscaleConfiguration              : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSApplicationGatewayAutoscaleConfiguration
CustomErrorConfigurations           : {}
PrivateLinkConfigurations           : {}
PrivateEndpointConnections          : {}
EnableHttp2                         : False
EnableFips                          : 
ForceFirewallPolicyAssociation      : 
Zones                               : {}
OperationalState                    : Running
ProvisioningState                   : Succeeded
Identity                            : 
GatewayIpConfigurationsText         : [
                                        {
                                          "Subnet": {
                                            "Id": "/subscriptions/6ca9eff3-3c2d-420e-875e-ea526b412ca0/resourceGroups/imran/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/imran-vnet/su
                                      bnets/appsubnet"
                                          },
                                          "ProvisioningState": "Succeeded",
                                          "Type": "Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/gatewayIPConfigurations",
                                          "Name": "appGatewayIpConfig",
                                          "Etag": "W/\"2494e0c1-b1fc-4840-896e-a39e9ebf0846\"",
                                          "Id": "/subscriptions/6ca9eff3-3c2d-420e-875e-ea526b412ca0/resourceGroups/imran/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/imran/gatew
                                      ayIPConfigurations/appGatewayIpConfig"
                                        }
```

This issue may cause having a different hostname at the reverse proxy in app gateway one of the back-end application servers can cause cookies or redirect URLs to malfunction. For instance, the session state may be lost, authentication may fail, or back-end URLs may unintentionally discover back-end URLs.

To resolve this issue, Try to add a custom domain Configure App Service with Application Gateway along with a certificate in your backend pool with use of custom domain and add authentication trusted root certificates of back-end servers like below:

[image]

[image]

In application gateway under setting click rules in backend target   -> add backend pool of app service and Add appropriate App Gateway in the HTTP configuration.

[image]

You can check the similar thread for ***reference***:

[when I hit application gateway's public ip, I get redirected to app service dns.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1022281/why-when-i-hit-application-gateways-public-ip-i-ge) by *GitaraniSharma*

[Azure application gateway with Web App - Gateway IP wont work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/639587/azure-application-gateway-with-web-app-gateway-ip)